# Create Directory Using PHP, Uploading Files on another domain account

Tags: php, file-upload, mkdir, create-directory

I need to upload files on an already existing folder from a php script on my account : www.example.com , on www.exampleuploads.com/uploads , but not able to do it ? Please help.

Also, my script detects that the folder does not exists (  but it actually does exists) , so it goes to mkdir , but mkdir also fails.

I am doing this :

```
if (directory for uploading does not exists)
{
    mkdir( 'http://www.exampleuploads.com/uploads', 0755)
}
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if it did work... it would be a hackers paradise

Answer (score 2):

You cant give a url like that , u need to specify the path in ur hosting dir..

```
eg :
mkdir( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'uploads', 0755);
//$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] this will give the path
```

Find path for http://www.exampleuploads.com in ur hosting server

Comment: sir, how do i find the path? please guide.

Comment: sir, but the domain is different ? its a separate account

Comment: Your hosting provider will also give u the path to ur directory in their server

Comment: No matter whatever the domain is $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] give the currently using domains directory path in server

Comment: but sir, i want to upload the file on www.exampleuploads.com/uploads from www.example.com , which is a different domain

Comment: @sqlchild - you can't using that method. Look at ftp or ssh if you have access to the other domain

Comment: mkdir( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'uploads', 0755);

use this script in the www.exampleuploads.com , as u need to create a folder there

Comment: no sir, i want to create folder from www.example.com ,on www.exampleuploads.com , is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

given path is the your reference path... called visual path its only handle bu the browser

to create directory you have to set the physical path of that server like DOCUMENT_ROOT and your folder path and for other domain you have a permission to create folder on the that server

you can achieve this path using $_SERVER['document_root']

Answer (score 1):

The function `mkdir` creates a directory on the server running the PHP script (`www.example.com`). If you want to create a directory on that server, you need to put the physical path (relative to the executing script or absolute).

You cannot create a new directory using a URL, even if they are hosted on the same server.

If they are not hosted on the same server, you cannot use `mkdir` on one server to create a directory on another server.